# Printing correct result of regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to write a strip function using regex.

This is my current code:

```py
import re

def makestringstripfun(text):
    stripStringRegex = re.compile(r'(^.*?)(\w+)( +\w+)*(\s|.*?)$')
    match = stripStringRegex.search(text)
    print(match)

print('Enter the string:')
text = input()
makestringstripfun(text)
```

I want to output the entire string, whatever I enter. Right now, if I enter the following text:

> smith john go home your shift getting over in the 30 minute later then why you here

the output of my code is:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 84), match='smith john go home your shift getting over in t>
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

The [`search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) method returns a match object, not a string.

See the documentation of [match objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) how to handle these. In short, you can use `match.group(0)` to get the first match group.

Tip: on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/6jFAoN/1) you can easily test your regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, what we like to match here.

If you wish to just output the entire string, maybe we might want to modify our expression and add a capturing group, something similar to:

```
^((.*?)(\w+)( +\w+)*(\s|.*?))$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/w5z8K5/1)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"^((.*?)(\w+)( +\w+)*(\s|.*?))$"

test_str = "smith john go home your shift getting over in the 30 minute later then why you here"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]